Listen for UDP packets on an EC2 instance with public IP
I have a Java app running on an EC2 container. It is periodically publishing packets to a UDP socket I have created using:
UnicastSendingMessageHandler udp = Udp.outboundAdapter("xyz.mydomain.io", OUTBOUND_PORT).getObject();

It also accepts incoming requests using an inbound adapter in a different port.
I've allowed inbound/outbound traffic and assigned a public IP to the EC2 container. I can send packets to the inbound port easily and confirm they're received using:
echo "test" | nc xyz.mydomain.io INBOUND_PORT

But how can I listen to the packets published to the OUTBOUND_PORT?
If i try
nc -l -u xyz.domain.io OUTBOUND_PORT

It will just say

Cannot assign requested address

I am not very familiar with internet protocols, so I am sure that I'm missing something. Any advice on how I can achieve this is appreciated.
